# JSON deserialize c# get values from class

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I'm trying to deserialize file .

My file  plik.json looks like : https://api.jsonstorage.net/v1/json/2fc690dd-fe2e-40cc-b7ce-a34b8326ed33

this is my code :

```
 public class Filter
    {
        public string filterType { get; set; }
        public string minPrice { get; set; }
        public string maxPrice { get; set; }
        public string tickSize { get; set; }
        public string multiplierUp { get; set; }
        public string multiplierDown { get; set; }
        public int? avgPriceMins { get; set; }
        public string minQty { get; set; }
        public string maxQty { get; set; }
        public string stepSize { get; set; }
        public string minNotional { get; set; }
        public bool? applyToMarket { get; set; }
        public int? limit { get; set; }
        public int? maxNumOrders { get; set; }
        public int? maxNumAlgoOrders { get; set; }
    }

    public class Symbol
    {
        public string symbol { get; set; }
        public string status { get; set; }
        public string baseAsset { get; set; }
        public int baseAssetPrecision { get; set; }
        public string quoteAsset { get; set; }
        public int quotePrecision { get; set; }
        public int quoteAssetPrecision { get; set; }
        public int baseCommissionPrecision { get; set; }
        public int quoteCommissionPrecision { get; set; }
        public List<string> orderTypes { get; set; }
        public bool icebergAllowed { get; set; }
        public bool ocoAllowed { get; set; }
        public bool quoteOrderQtyMarketAllowed { get; set; }
        public bool isSpotTradingAllowed { get; set; }
        public bool isMarginTradingAllowed { get; set; }
        public List<Filter> filters { get; set; }
        public List<string> permissions { get; set; }
    }

    public class Root
    {
        public List<Symbol> symbols { get; set; }
    }

    private void button29_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader("C:\\Users\\Adamsz\\Pictures\\plik.json"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Before");
            string json = r.ReadToEnd();
           // Console.WriteLine(json);
            Root myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json);
            Console.WriteLine("After");

        }

        
           List<Symbol> xd = new List<Symbol>();
        foreach (var m in xd)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(m.symbol.ToString());
            List <Filter> filtr = new List<Filter>();
            foreach (var x in filtr)
            {
                if (x.filterType == "LOT_SIZE")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(x.minQty);
                }
                   
            }
        }
       

    }
```

Now i have a problem with WrtieLine. What should i change in my code to get exacly this output? Thanks in advance!
OutPut should be like :

ETHBTC

0.00100000

LTCBTC

0.01000000

Comment: Why you expecting that `xd = new List<Symbol>()` has some elements ? `xd` should be take from `Root` instance which you deserialize

Comment: @Selvin Could you tell how can i get exacly this values from Root?

Comment: by accesssing its only property and assiging to variable

Comment: Please write in answer if you can and if you know exacly how.

Comment: I know but sometime is hard to make something . And i wanted some help here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 List<Symbol> symbols = myDeserializedClass.symbols;
            foreach (var m in symbols)
            {

                Console.WriteLine(m.symbol.ToString());
                List<Filter> filtr = m.filters;
                foreach (var x in filtr)
                {
                    if(x.filterType == "LOT_SIZE")
                    Console.WriteLine(x.minQty);
                }
            }
```

This is what i was looking for...